# ExtJS 2.3: Tooltip on checkbox boxlabel

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, checkbox, tooltip

I am working on ExtJS 2.3 (yep, pretty old, but legacy) and want to display a checkbox with long label. I am able to show partial label with ellipsis using CSS but now I want to display the full label as tooltip. I tried following but it adds tooltip to just the checkbox and not on the label. Can someone please help?

```
var checkbox = new Ext.form.Checkbox({
                boxLabel : item.displayName,
                checked : item.selected,
                name : item.internalName,
                listeners : {
                    render : function(event) {
                        Ext.QuickTips.register({
                            target: event.el,
                            text: event.boxLabel
                          });
                    }
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented the tooltip with following code. Would like to know the comments from others

```
x.y.CheckboxWithTooltip = Ext.extend(Ext.form.Checkbox, {
    itemCls : 'checkboxCSS',
    listeners : {
        afterrender : function(event) {
            enclosingElem = event.getResizeEl();
            enclosingElem.on('mouseenter', this.onMouseEnterFunction, event);
        }
    },
    onMouseEnterFunction : function(elem, t) {
        t.qtip = this.toolTip;
    }
});
```

CSS for this defined as

```
.checkboxCSS .x-form-check-wrap {
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 105px;
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```